# Write If else for unit testing jasmine

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I just start learn using jasmine. I am confused if I need testing function which the value is the function as well, like this is the case
on **component.ts**

```
 validationLoadListDownload() {
    if (this.getGroupId === 0) {
      this.loadListDownloadRequest();
    } else {
      this.loadListDownloadRequestGroup();
    }
  }
```

if like that, how do we write it on component.spec.ts? I am confused, thank you

Comment: Give it a try first. If you face any problem post that here.

Answer (score 1):

it can be done something like this;

```
it('should download the validation list when getGroupId is zero', () => {
  const loadListDownloadRequestSpy = spyOn(component, 'loadListDownloadRequest');
  component.getGroupId = 0;
  component.validationLoadListDownload();
  expect(loadListDownloadRequestSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
});


it('should download the validation list when getGroupId is not zero', () => {
  const loadListDownloadRequestGroupSpy = spyOn(component, 'loadListDownloadRequestGroup');
  component.getGroupId = 5;
  component.validationLoadListDownload();
  expect(loadListDownloadRequestGroupSpy ).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```